# How to send Elliptic Curve public key from java client to js server?

Tags: javascript, java

I'm doing an application where server verifies client using EC cryptography.
For that I need a method to send public key to the server.

This is my code that generates public key:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class StoreKeys{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
        ECGenParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
        keyGen.initialize(ecSpec);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
    }
}
```

I've already tried to send key as coordinates (to regenerate it) and as PEM, but none of methods I've found worked for me.

For connection to server I'm using TCP
'net' library for nodejs.

Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: What problem did you have with sending a PEM? The conversion in and out or the transmission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the client side (Java) you need to convert the key into a transmissible string. I suggest the following:

```
String serialisedPublicKey = publicKey.getModulus().toString() + "|" +
    publicKey.getPublicExponent().toString();
```

Convert it back to the public key with js using [node-rsa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa):

```
    const parts = serialisedPublicKey.split(‘|’);
   

   const publicKey = key.importKey({
    n: +parts[0],
    e: +parts[1]
}, 'components-public');
```

I would transmit by creating an http client on the Java side and an http server (eg express) on the nodejs side. Way easier than tcp wrangling)

Comment: Thank you for reply. My problem is to regenerate key in js, not to actually send it. Have looked all over the internet and found nothing

Comment: Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa. I updated my answer. However, passing a PEM is more usual and simpler. What problem did you encounter with this approach?

Comment: Thanks again. My problem was in every method i've tried just returned errors, but now everything seems to be good.